# How to Remove an item from an array of class using RemoveAll() and Where() in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class object:

```
Student student = new Student("Ram",20, new Address(hNo: 10, sNo: "10"), new Marks[] { new Marks("Maths", 90), new Marks("Science", 80), new Marks("Physics", 95) });
```

When I am removing items from class using RemoveAll() method, I get below error:

> cannot convert from
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to
>   'System.Predicate'

This is the code I am using:

```
string subject="Maths";
student.marks.ToList().RemoveAll(student.marks.Where(x => x.subject != marks));
```

I want to remove Marks("Maths", 90) from the student class object, but failing.

Comment: Have you read the docs for RemoveAll? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx . As the error message suggests it expects a predictae, not a list of items to remove (though I note that's not what you are giving it either).

Comment: @Chris can you give an answer through the answer panel. It will help thank you.

Comment: I wasn't quite sure what you were actually wanting to remove and from where which is why I didn't make it an answer. ie although I thought I could be helpful in explaining the error I wasn't sure I was in a position to give a good answer as to how to do what you were wanting to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `RemoveAll` method expects you to give it a lambda expression that it will use to filter for items to be removed, and you are giving it a collection of items that match your criteria.

Just change the call to have the expression only and you're done:

```
string subject="Maths";
student.marks = student.marks.Where(x => x.subject == subject).ToArray();
```

Comment: pfff.....fair enough, if it were a list already, that would not be a problem....let me fix that :)

Comment: @dutzu it's not removing anything??

Comment: @yogihosting yep, because marks is an array and you had cast it to list and thus the removal was decoupled from the source. Try the new version I posted

Comment: @yogihosting glad to help, make sure to mark it as the answer

Comment: you haven't used RemoveAll() for it. Is it cannot be done with .removeALL() ?

Comment: It can, but then it would make sense that you change Marks to be a List instead of an Array. Change its type to List<Marks> and you can use RemoveAll, but again, pass the predicate not the expression with the Where clause.

Answer (score 5):

Let's break this down to something simpler:

```
Marks[] marks = new Marks[]
{
    new Marks("Maths", 90),
    new Marks("Science", 80),
    new Marks("Physics", 95)
};
```

That gives me:

[image: marks]

Now, if I do this:

```
List<Marks> list = marks.ToList();
```

I end up with a **copy** of `marks`. I have this:

[image: list]

Now if I call `list.RemoveAll(x => x.Subject != "Maths");` I remove all but the `"Maths"` subject from `list`. It now looks like this:

[image: list (2)]

But since this was a **copy** of `marks` then `marks` is still the same:

[image: marks (2)]

Since `marks` is an array you cannot remove any elements unless you recreate the array. LINQ offers an easy way to do this like this:

```
marks = marks.Where(x => x.Subject != "Maths").ToArray();
```

That's what you should be doing.

Alternatively make the `Marks` property of your `Student` class a `List<Marks>` and not a `Marks[]`.

```
public class Student
{
    public Student(List<Marks> marks)
    {
        this.Marks = marks;
    }
    public List<Marks> Marks;
}
```

Then you can call `RemovalAll` directly on it, like this:

```
List<Marks> marks = new List<Marks>()
{
        new Marks("Maths", 90),
        new Marks("Science", 80),
        new Marks("Physics", 95)
};

var students = new Student(marks);

students.Marks.RemoveAll(x => x.Subject != "Maths");
```

Comment: If i want to do it from .RemoveAll() method then how it can be achieved??

Comment: @yogihosting - I've added how to use `.RemoveAll()` to the bottom of my answer.